# Express failing to load iframe contents from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

When I try to use an iframe to load another (local) webpage, express fails to load the contents of the iframe

**`/index.html`** (loader)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Not important</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="/pages/test.html" width="" height=""></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`main.js`**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 7077;

app.use("/", express.static("public"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

`Error`:

```
Cannot GET /test.html
```

File hierarchy:

```
project folder
| main.js
| public
| | index.html
| | pages
| | | test.html
| | |_
| |_
|_
```

Edit to add: If i load `/pages/test.html` in my web browser directly, that works fine. It's just when it's in an iframe.

Edit: Nevermind. Is an issue with firefox, not my code (yay?)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, I think you must put your pages folder inside the public folder, like that:

[image]

The code is the same as yours

Comment: That's what I did. I've added a file hierarchy to the question. Thanks though

Comment: I try here and works for me. I don't know the cause your code doesn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/prova-bnsu6?file=/package.json